# gem install rails doesn't do anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I installed Ruby and RubyGems on Ubuntu 10.04. Ruby is version 1.8.7. Gems is version 1.3.7. When I try sudo gem install rails, nothing happens. It just hangs forever. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It'll take quite some time to install rails - there are lot of dependencies and these need to be downloaded - if you have a slow connection, just wait for a bit.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was expecting an immediate response of some kind like with apt-get.

Comment: I was on the same boat as you - thought it had given up but it was processing in the background.

Comment: I have a lightning fast connection on a VPS server and this is still happening

Answer (score 171):

Try adding -V (upper case) to the end of the install command, if forces the command to be verbose, so you can see things going on. Eg:

```
sudo gem install rails -V
```

Comment: Another thing to consider... open Task Manager (or equivalent - I'm using Xubuntu) and view process by CPU usage. That's the only indication I had that gem was actually doing anything until it eventually finished.

Comment: It was using so little CPU that I still didn't think it was doing anything. I tried `-v` but that didn't work - had to be uppercase!

Comment: seriously thank you, thought my gems was broken

Comment: That's what I am looking for!

Comment: Wow. At least they could have echoed something, well _anything_, to the console. I just assumed that I had to run as root or something similar.

Comment: `-V` was very helpful. I had a conflict for the rails binary, where it asked to overwrite `y/n` (expecting an action). But without `-V` it wouldn't even display that message and it just hangs as a result of this.

Answer (score 2):

1. try to add -V (upper-case) in the parameter, to show more detail of what is downloading
2. if it still very slow or pending somewhere, it normally indicates a low internet connection to the rubygems.org site(showing in the output window). you can try to update the source of the gem using, by

   gem source -r https://rubygems.org/

   gem source -a "your new source site"

in my country, after I switch to http://ruby.taobao.org, it only takes 1min to complete the installation.

Comment: First option is better than just waiting for an empty line to show something

Answer (score 0):

In addition to monitoring with the `-V` flag, it's also worth checking that you can pull anything from the internet first.  If you're not sure (new server, for example), try `wget -O/dev/null https://rubygems.org/` and see if there is trouble retrieving the source site.